ReadStream (Cassandra) ordering and Futures (Cassandra request) - Like SQL join
I have two cassandra tables.
One first table containing contacts identifier (time based UUID) for a mailing list. It is important that the final solution respects the order of insertion in this first table. I've no choice because if my application crashes i have to restart on the last contact identifier (time based UUID).
The second table contains the detail of each user.
I create a vertx Cassandra row stream on the first table. In the handler of this stream, i've to read the detail from the second table. This reading is asynchronous (future). That involves that when i get my user detail, this is no more in the order of the first table.
I think that this behaviour should be addressed by Vertx, but i did not find anything in the documentation.
Is there anyone who meets this problem, and who have found a solution?
